# Problems with committing UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, tfs, uwp

I have created an app project using Xamarin and UWP, and now I have to commit it to Team Foundation, but I see a lot of errors saying, that it cannot find files.

An example is this `project.UWP.Shared\App.xaml.cs: Could not find a part of the path 'project.UWP.Shared\App.xaml.cs'.`, and I understand that it cannot find the file, but when I look in the solution it exist in another place `project.UWP\App.xaml.cs`. How can I come around this problem?

I tried excluding `project.UWP.Shared` even though I do not find it as a good solution, but then it occurs with logos.

**UPDATE**
A screenshot of the error
[image: Screenshot]

A screenshot of TFS pane
[image]

Comment: Where exactly it says so (in Errors pane, in TFS output pane ...) ? Can you post a screenshot? Do you use a gated check-in? Are you sure that all those files are considered new by TFS (perhaps some of them are without the `+` symbol before file name)?

Comment: In the TFS pane, when I am trying to commit. A screendump is coming up soon.

Comment: It is probably caused by some synchronization issue between what TFS thinks is in your project and what is actually in your project in VS (yeah, that happens sometimes with TFS and VS). You can try to open Team Explorer -> Source Control Explorer, then find and remove the nonexistent file manually. If it is not shown there you can create the file at that location, add it to your solution and remove it - that should work for sure. Also perhaps something in TFS power tools may be of use, though I am not sure.

Comment: @EugenePodskal I think so, but I just find it wierd, cause I have just added UWP to that project.

Comment: That's an auto generated file.  It shouldn't be included in commits.